# How does work meta-character '.' with character class

Tags: regex, character-class

I've learned about regular expressions recently. So far I had no problems with understanding, but there is one case which confuses me:

```
.+[123]
```

If I understand it correctly, in this case expression ".+" should iterate through every character **until one of this characters appears [123]**. However in cases like this:

> **abc abc abc 21 efg efg 23**44

It matches "**abc abc abc 21 efg efg 23**" ignoring 2,1,2.

Why does it happen? *(I use regex101.com for checking)*

I used search in order to find something, but I didn't find anything about this case. 
I made a workaround **[^123]+[123]**, but I want to understand why this happens.

Comment: `.+` matches 1+ chars as many as possible, `.+?` will match 1+ chars as few as possible.

Comment: Look at the regex101 debugger

Comment: And make sure you read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, all tutorials I've read or watched didn't mention about this. This comment is answer to my question.